# Update AngularJS data from separate source

Tags: angularjs

I'm working on my first Angular project and I've been thinking of the best way to word this question for a while now but I'm going to give this a shot.

I'm building an app that uses the Veralite (MiOS) to return device data in json format. The first request returns all of the devices on the system (example below).

```
"devices":[  
      {  
         "name":"Bedroom Light",
         "altid":"4",
         "id":6,
         "category":2,
         "subcategory":0,
         "room":0,
         "parent":1,
         "status":"0",
         "level":"0",
         "state":-1,
         "comment":""
      },
      {  
         "name":"Office Light",
         "altid":"6",
         "id":18,
         "category":2,
         "subcategory":0,
         "room":0,
         "parent":1,
         "level":"0",
         "status":"0",
         "state":-1,
         "comment":""
      }
```

Once all of the devices are returned, my script begins long polling the vera engine. Once a change to a device is made the results of the long poll are returned, but the results only include the devices that were changed (example below).

```
"devices":[  
      {  
         "altid":"6",
         "id":"18",
         "subcategory":"0",
         "room":"0",
         "parent":"1",
         "level":"20",
         "status":"1",
         "state":"4",
         "comment":"Office Light: Transmit was ok"
      }
```

What I am trying to wrap my head around, is the proper way to update the existing devices array with the newly updated data. Would I need to convert them to arrays, then loop through each array and try to match them by keys?

Hopefully I asked this as clearly as possible.

**EDIT:** *Just to update this a bit for anyone that stumbles across this, specifically people interested in developing for the Veralite. The ID returned from the original request will be returned as an integer, but when long polling the engine, the ID will be returned as a string. So even though the selected answer is correct, you'll need to either parse the updated device ID as an integer (parseInt), or only use a == instead of a === when filtering the devices.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through the object fields just like you can loop through an array with Object.keys.

Conceptually something like:

Step 1) Find the updated product, by the field id:

```
var previousVersionDevice = $scope.devices.filter(function(item) {
    return item.id === updateDevice.id; // Keep only the one existing device that matches id
})[0];
```

Step 2) Loop through the keys in the product and overwrite the previous values with the ones received.

```
Object.keys(updatedDevice).forEach(function(key) {
    previousVersionDevice[key] = updatedDevice[key]; // Overwrite/add all from updated version
});
```

Comment: Fair enough, but then how do I push that new value to the $scope variable?

Comment: If you just update the field values you don't have update the $scope variable (I assume it's the array, $scope.devices) at all.

Comment: Would this be the same approach assuming that multiple updated devices were returned after the polling? Would I nest loops?

Comment: With multiple devices you could modify step 1 to check for all the updated devices and return true if item.id matches any of them - filter returns an array. Instead of selecting just item [0] do a forEach on that array in step two and loop through the keys of each device in the array.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can loop through and find the matching device via some sort of unique key (assuming `id` is unique and won't change, you can use that).